# VisualStudio - library project that joins multiple library projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a solution with multiple library projects, say "LibA", "LibB", "LibC".  Those libs contain some utilities created by me, that I use in my other solutions.

Now I'd like to create one more lib ("TotalLib") project that combines all other, to have all utilities, extensions in a single library.

I know, that I can add each file from each lib as link to my "TotalLib", but that is troublesome to add every file now and every new file each time one is created. Is there any other, simpler way to join all files from other projects into that "TotalLib" project?

Comment: Can't you add a reference to your library?

Comment: Just adding a reference will not allow me to use classes and methods from those referenced libs in an application project, where i want to reference only this "TotalLib". ... at least i think i can't.

Comment: yup, i was right, just adding reference to other projects as lib won't let me use code from those libs, when i reference "total" in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Since those are your libraries, add a common topmost namespace to all the libraries (or add them to one of the existing namespace) and compile them in one project. Then, reference this aggregate DLL.

Comment: Each one of them have the same root namespace, or sometimes my classes are added to e.g. System.Windows.Forms if it is a control. This meets your requirements ;) but what do you mean by "compile them in one project" - I want to do exactly that, but how to do it?

Comment: I mean to really merge the libraries into one project.

Comment: Continued: When adding a reference, you need a dll, but separate projects in a solution compile as separate dlls so your TotalLib never contains its parts. You can merge them by creating the TotalLib  and use "add existing item" to add all files from your partial libraries. Compile and voilá.